# PHP problem if(strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/' , $_POST["msg"])=="TEXT")

Tags: php

Do you know where is problem with this code:

I see all the time: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' 2

PHP problem with this code:

```
if(strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/' ,$_POST["msg"])=="TEXT"){
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "serwer33830_db", "ICh*%m@72112L@&", "serwer33830_db");
```

I don't know where what is wrong in line:

```
if(strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/' ,$_POST["msg"])=="TEXT"){
```

Comment: On the line you mention you are missing a parentheses

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php , you're missing a required parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/' ,$_POST["msg"])=="TEXT")){
```

missing ) before {

Comment: Labradorcode thanks!